# Having trouble removing all nodes from a linked-list

Tags: c, linked-list

This code deletes all nodes except the last one. But I want it to delete all nodes. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
deleteall(struct node **start)
{           
    struct node*temp,*curr;             
    while ((*start)->next!=NULL)
    {               
        temp=*start;                
        *start=(*start)->next;                                  
        free(temp);             
        curr=(*start);                                          
    }           
    if ((*start)->next==NULL)
    {                           
        free(curr);         
    }       
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't delete the last node?

Answer (score 2):

I created a basic implementation of a linked list and tested your code. It's not particularly pretty, but it works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node { struct node *next; };

struct node* create_node(struct node *next) {
    struct node* node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->next = next;
    printf("created %p\n", node);
    return node;
}

void deleteall(struct node **start)
{           
    struct node*temp,*curr;             
    while ((*start)->next!=NULL)
    {               
        temp=*start;                
        *start=(*start)->next;                                  
        free(temp);             
        printf("free'd %p\n", temp);
        curr=(*start);                                          
    }           
    if ((*start)->next==NULL)
    {                           
        free(curr);         
        printf("free'd %p\n", curr);

    }       
}  

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // create root node
    struct node * ll = create_node(0);
    // insert three nodes
    ll->next = create_node(ll->next);
    ll->next = create_node(ll->next);
    ll->next = create_node(ll->next);
    // delete all nodes (including root) 
    deleteall(&ll);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
created 0xc3c010
created 0xc3c030
created 0xc3c050
created 0xc3c070
free'd 0xc3c010
free'd 0xc3c070
free'd 0xc3c050
free'd 0xc3c030
```

As you can see, all nodes that are allocated are actually free'd.

Maybe you are confused by the fact, that the root node is not set to 0, but [apparantly still contains the remains of the object previously located at that place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/1025391). You could fix that if you assign 0 to the start pointer after you freed the nodes: `*start = 0;` (or by eliminating the additional `curr` pointer, as suggested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39842118/1025391)).

---

Consider that you could alternatively delete the nodes of your list recursively:

```
void delete_node_recursively(struct node *node) {
    if (node) {
        delete_node_recursively(node->next);
        free(node)
    }
}
```

If you want to have the root node set to 0 in the end, you can add a wrapper:

```
void delete_list(struct node **root) {
    delete_node_recursively(*root);
    *root = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
This was to simplify your code.
And Finally `*start` become `NULL`. (your code not become `NULL`)

```
deleteall(struct node **start){
    struct node *temp;
    while(*start){
        temp = *start;
        *start=(*start)->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```